# How to change existing element of the list?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a method for updating existing element of the list, I found ount that i need to use indexWhere or firstWhere to updating existing items in my list, but the problem is that either the changes are not made at all, or the changes by changing a random existing element of the list replace the first element of the list. I need that when changing an existing element, it is the existing element that changes and does not replace the first element of the list

```
void _changeAddress(AddressChangeEvent event, Emitter<AddressesState> emit) {
    final AddressModel changedAddress = event.changedModel;
    final List<AddressModel>? list = state.addresses.value;
    if (list != null) {
      final int index = list.indexWhere((AddressModel element) => element.id == changedAddress.id);

      if (index != -1) {
        list[index] = changedAddress;
        emit(
          state.copyWith(
            addresses: list),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because a list is a reference object, using the same state instance might not trigger widget tree rebuild.

Change `final List<AddressModel>? list = state.addresses.value;`

to

`final List<AddressModel>? list = List.from(state.addresses.value);`

Comment: your hint worked, but now when I change an element, the changes happen instantly, but if I change any random element of the list, it always replaces the first element after saving the change. there's probably something wrong with the fact that I'm accessing the element by index How to fix it?

Comment: I think you should check `event.changedModel` maybe its `id` is always equal to the first item in the list.